# Tag creation time in a SVN repository

Tags: svn

How can I determine tag creation time in a subversion / SVN repository?

Comment: Isn't it something like: "svn log -v <tag address>", then just look at the date.

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer. I can not accept your comment as a solution or mark it as useful.

Comment: I use tortoise most of the time, so I'm never sure about the command line options...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do:
`svn log --stop-on-copy <tag-adress>`
 it will stop the output in the point when the "creation" of the tag was made.

Answer (score 3):

You can find out the log information from the repository by using a command like:

```
svn log -v <tag address>
```

You can then just look at the date that it was copied from the source.